# Working with an Array inside Your Theme Options Array - Multiple Values

Tags: themes, array, options

I apologize if this is covered extensively elsewhere, I'm not sure how to phrase my searches on the topic.

Basically, instead of the following standard code to store data in WP-options...

```
$options = array (
array("name" => __('Font','mytheme'),
    "desc" => __('Change the font face)','mytheme'),
    "id" => "mytheme_font",
    "std" => "Arial",
    "type" => "text"),
array("name" => __('Alternate Font','mytheme'),
    "desc" => __('Change the alternate font face)','mytheme'),
    "id" => "mytheme_font_alternate",
    "std" => "Tahoma",
    "type" => "text"),
);
```

I would instead like to store multiple values in the "std" portion, with its own array - like this:

```
    $options = array (
        array("name" => __('Font','mytheme'),
            "desc" => __('Change the font face)','mytheme'),
            "id" => "mytheme_font",
            "std" => array('size' => '10px', 'face' => 'Arial', 'color' => '#000000'),
            "type" => "text"),
        array("name" => __('Alternate Font','mytheme'),
            "desc" => __('Change the alternate font face)','mytheme'),
            "id" => "mytheme_font_alternate",
            "std" => array('size' => '13px', 'face' => 'Tahoma', 'color' => '#FF0000'),
            "type" => "text"),
        );
```

I would assume this is allowed, but given that it is, I am at a loss for how to:

**1)** Know which name/id to use on the admin form inputs to signify to go into "size" and "face" and "color".

For example, in the standard code without the multidimensional array I would usually use code like this:

```
<input name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option( $value['id'], $value['std'] )); ?>" />
```

I'm not sure what to place in the "name" and "id" sections for the input.

**2)** How would I retrieve these values in the WP theme?  I usually use code like this:

```
// Make values available
global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
$$value['id'] = get_option($value['id'], $value['std']);
}

// Print the actual value
<?php echo $mytheme_font; ?>;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  If anyone has any ideas or knows of any tutorials on this topic that would be excellent!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this array for example usage:

```
$options = array(
    "name" => __('Font','mytheme'),
    "desc" => __('Change the font face)','mytheme'),
    "id" => "mytheme_font",
    "std" => array('size' => '10px', 'face' => 'Arial', 'color' => '#000000'),
    "type" => "text",
 );
```

For question 1, to reference nested arrays, just reference them directly.

`echo $options['std']['size'];`

In the form input, if using the [Settings API](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/):

`name="mytheme_options[std][size]"`

Regarding question 2, it appears to me that you're probably doing it wrong to being with, as that bit of code you have there makes no real sense. What is `get_option($value['id'], $value['std']);` supposed to do anyway?

You'd get your options array from the database like this:

`$options = get_option('mytheme_options');`

Individual options would then be like `$options['name']` or `$options['std']['face']` or what have you.

Comment: Hi Otto, thanks for the help!  I updated some of the code in my original question.  If my $options array has many arrays within it, how would I access specific arrays within it?

For example would I use an integer like this to access the 2nd array?  `$options[1]['std']['size']`

I tried that but it didn't work.  My starter code is from Sitepoint's "Build Your Own Wicked WordPress Themes" book.

Comment: I just made a test with your code and referencing it by `$options[1]['std']['size'];` works fine for me.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the part that is breaking it for me is the "mytheme_options" you used as the parameter for the "get_option" function.  Where does "mytheme_options" come from and what is it?  Is it an array I should have already created?  Is it an array that WP automatically creates based on my themename and adds "options" to the end of its name?

Comment: No, that's just a name I made up to designate where the options are saving. You're saving your own options, presumably you would know where they are, right?